# Blocking blank value entry into a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database into which i enter values through an application. To be specific ,i enter certain value in a text-box and click on save Button which handles the task of saving it into the database.  The problem that i'm facing is even when i don't enter any value in the text-box and click on save button the value gets saved into the database( A case which i should have handled in the code ). Now i want to write a SQL-script so that it blocks the entry of the blank values into the database .

for example lets say ..books be the table which contains columns author_name , price , year

so if a try to enter a blank author name and try saving it, it should not be saved

I tried this:

```
 DELIMITER |

 CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT ON books
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.author_name= '' THEN    
  delete from books where author_name= '';
  END IF;      
END;
|books
DELIMITER ;
```

can anyone tell me how to do this , is there any other method to achieve this ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't change the code?

Comment: does your table definition allow NULL in that column?  Does the code (that you can't change) have error handling for a failed insert? When you say that you cannot change code are you saying that you cannot change the SQL for the insert/update etc either?

Comment: I cannot change the code now :(   @ gillyspy  the table doesn't allow null values .Yes the code has an error handling mechanism for failed insert .yes i cannot change sql for either update/insert .

Answer (score 1):

You should validate user input in the application.

Comment: I think this is the best answer if you can implement this, no need to do stuff on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER <name of the trigger> BEFORE INSERT ON <name of table>
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF NEW.<fieldname> = ''
      THEN
        SET NEW='Error: Cannot insert record empty value for <fieldname>';
      END IF;
    END
    ;
```

Create the trigger **BEFORE** insert

Comment: If you want to generate error you can look at this: http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea..

You could also use a check constraint to prevent "illegal" inserts.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

I would recommend sanitizing the input at the source (the app) though.

Answer (score 0):

check the input value for emptiness in the application, this should be one part of your application logic. `if empty, dont insert` - thats it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called "constraint":

```
ALTER TABLE books MODIFY author_name varchar(200) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: He asked about empty strings, your answer deals with null values.

Comment: its not null value that i want to block , its the blank values ?

Comment: Isn't the empty string a null value in mysql? With Oracle it's the same, I think.